# HTTP Client PostAsync return status 500

Tags: c#, http-post, httpclient

I send POST request to API. This is my code:

```
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                    var postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claim);
                    var response = await client.PostAsync($"api/Claims/Save", new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

I seriallize object and send but in the API my code is this:

```
   [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Save(string user , string description , string data)
```

If is HTTP GET i know you add parameters on the url but i don't know how to make with HTTP POST. The problem is i can't change API requests.

Claim object contains string user , string description , string data

**The API is not mine, I cannot modify it.**

Answer (score 0):

If anyone came in same situation:

First u need to add Content-Type:`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Second u need to create a Dictionary depending on your values ex:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    dictionary.Add("values", "Doctor");
                    dictionary.Add("name", "John");
                    dictionary.Add("surname", "Doe");
                    dictionary.Add("Year", "1993");
```

Third u need to Encode the content like this:

`var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dictionary);`

And last send the request:

`var response = await client.PostAsync($"api/Claims/Save", content);`